# Postfix sending mail from local users but not from mailman

Tags: postfix, centos6, mailman

I am attempting to set up a Mailman server for a local club and have run into a strange issue with Postfix and Mailman. I think the issue lies with Postfix.

So The issue is that I am able to send mail from local users via the mail command, however I am not receiving mails when trying to send them from mailman.

Here is an example from /var/log/maillog of an email that was sent and I WAS able to receive:

```
May  1 20:15:17 vps-1152677-20287 postfix/pickup[16784]: ED274AA901B1: uid=0 from=<root>
May  1 20:15:17 vps-1152677-20287 postfix/cleanup[16844]: ED274AA901B1: message-id=<20150502001517.ED274AA901B1@mail.akblacksmith.club>
May  1 20:15:17 vps-1152677-20287 postfix/qmgr[16785]: ED274AA901B1: from= <root@akblacksmith.club>, size=447, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  1 20:15:18 vps-1152677-20287 postfix/smtp[16845]: ED274AA901B1: to=<KroniK.icy@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.29.26]:25, delay=0.57, delays=0.02/0/0.13/0.43, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1430525718 f194si28051230qhe.11                                   2 - gsmtp)
May  1 20:15:18 vps-1152677-20287 postfix/qmgr[16785]: ED274AA901B1: removed
```

Here is an example of an email that was sent from mailman which I did NOT receive:

```
May  1 20:14:50 vps-1152677-20287 postfix/smtpd[16889]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May  1 20:14:50 vps-1152677-20287 postfix/smtpd[16889]: 6258BAA901B1: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
May  1 20:14:50 vps-1152677-20287 postfix/cleanup[16844]: 6258BAA901B1: message-id=<mailman.0.1430525688.16888.akblacksmiths@mail.akblacksmith.club>
May  1 20:14:50 vps-1152677-20287 postfix/qmgr[16785]: 6258BAA901B1: from=<akblacksmiths-bounces@mail.akblacksmith.club>, size=2034, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May  1 20:14:50 vps-1152677-20287 postfix/smtpd[16889]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May  1 20:14:51 vps-1152677-20287 postfix/smtp[16845]: 6258BAA901B1: to=<KroniK.icy@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.29.26]:25, delay=0.86, delays=0/0/0.16/0.7, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1430525691 134si28040121qhx.99 - gsmtp)
May  1 20:14:51 vps-1152677-20287 postfix/qmgr[16785]: 6258BAA901B1: removed
```

Im guessing it has something to do with the connection from localhost, however I thought I had that covered in the postfix config.

Here is my main.cf for Postfix:

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = mail.akblacksmith.club
mydomain = akblacksmith.club
myorigin = akblacksmith.club
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination = mail.akblacksmith.club, akblacksmith.club, localhost.akblacksmith.club, localhost, localhost.localdomain
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
relay_domains = $mydestination
relayhost =
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/etc/mailman/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
recipient_delimiter = +
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
```

Im not quite sure why postfix would send one message but not the other.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, Gmail was under the impression that the mailman emails were spam...

Comment: You can accept your own answer, too, and it is a big help for the googlers of the future.

Comment: It required me to wait 48 hours before I could accept my own answer... Stupid rules.